# nvd3 CSS override for more than 2 line charts

Tags: html, css, nvd3.js

I am not clear that how to override nvd3 CSS and apply it to the different line charts.

In Html, there are two div for line plots.

```
<div id="offsetDiv">
      <div id="plot1" class='with-3d-shadow with-transitions'>
      <svg></svg>
</div>

<div id="offsetDiv">
    <div id="plot1" class='with-3d-shadow with-transitions'>
      <svg></svg>
</div>
```

In a CSS file, I can modify the value of opacity to apply. Also, I want to have different value to apply another plot.

```
.nvd3.nv-line .nvd3.nv-scatter .nv-groups .nv-point {
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
}

.something-new-class-name {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke-opacity: 0;
}
```

I tried to put new class name in div, but it doesn't work.
Please point out what is wrong.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try using chart id, the folowing works for me.

```
#growthChart .nv-series-7 .nv-point {
fill-opacity: 0;
stroke-opacity: 1;}
```

Also check that your css is loaded in the very end, after the nvd3 css, and then check in dev tools if your css is applied or not.

Comment: thanks but it does affect two plots. the question is affecting different opacity to two charts in a single page. @zaini

Comment: I am guessing now, how about using plot1 and plot2 as ids instead of using plot1 for both divs.

And then using ids to apply different css.